# MongoDB service goes down while inserting data

Tags: python, windows, mongodb

I am running MongoDB 4.2.8 on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and I want to simply insert a lot of data into the database, using Python and PyMongo.

It worked fine at first, but after inserting a certain number of records (~2 million), the MongoDB service went down. I deleted the data and ran my program again, the same thing still happened.

I couldn't find out the cause of this problem.

Here are the [error messages](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11OMNSKVMh8oMYX6s72kLrCwI7yFzi357/view) that I copied from the log file.

EDIT: The first line of the error messages is

> 2020-07-17T18:00:51.614+0800 E  STORAGE  [conn38247] WiredTiger error (0) [1594980051:613746][17560:140711179997792], file:collection-8-5621763546278059960.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_block_read_off, 283: collection-8-5621763546278059960.wt: read checksum error for 32768B block at offset 4277100544: block header checksum of 0xf5304876 doesn't match expected checksum of 0x1ea56329 Raw: [1594980051:613746]

Comment: There's a 3.10.1 version of pymongo; try updating to that.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the first log line marked as an error `E` so that the question does not loose all of its future value when you remove that file from your google drive.

Comment: @BellyBuster I've tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: Keep an eye on memory use while running your program. If your exhausting your memory odd things could happen.

Answer (score 0):

The error `wt: read checksum error` indicates that the storage engine read a block whose checksum did not match the data.

This implies that the data on disk was changed after being written by the mongod process and is no longer self-consistent.

Make sure that you aren't trying to run 2 different mongod processes with the same data directory, and that there are no other processes trying to access these files.

Comment: I am sure that there is only one process working with that data directory, and the insertion works fine for a certain time. I don't understand why the data is changed because I am the only user of that server, running only one program. Could you list other possibilities? Thank you!!

Comment: An obvious way to check is to stop the "known" mongo service and see if you can still connect to the instance.

Comment: @BellyBuster No, I can't connect to the instance if the only 'known' MongoDB service is stopped. However, is it possible that this problem is caused by hardware damage? Like broken HDDs.

Comment: You might monitor the open file list to see if anything else touches that directory.  A common culprit is a virus scanner.  Another possibility is network flakiness if it is a remote file system.